# Preserve JUnit XML Report structure with Maven Surefire

Tags: java, maven, gitlab-ci, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to preserve the JUnit style XML-Report when creating reports through maven test.
I am using features of JUnit 5 such as `DynamicTest` (`TestFactory`), `Nested`, `ParameterizedTest`.
Those features enables me to structure my tests and therefore the testresults displayed in my eclipse IDE.

When running JUnit5 Tests in Eclipse I get a structured view of my tests. But with Maven surefire (maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4), the reports are just in a flat hierarchy.

Example:

```
public class Example {
    @Nested
    public class ExampleA {
        @ParameterizedTest
        @ValueSource(strings = {"Foo1A", "Bar1A"})
        void test1A(String input) {}

        @ParameterizedTest
        @ValueSource(strings = {"Foo2A", "Bar2A"})
        void test2A(String input) {}

    }
    @Nested
    public class ExampleB {
        @ParameterizedTest
        @ValueSource(strings = {"FooB", "BarB"})
        void testB(String input) {}
    }
}
```

Results when Running in Eclipse:

[image]

When running as surefire report: `mvn -Dtest=Example* clean test` it results in three files: one empty for the parent test-case, and two flat ones for the nested test-cases. They also miss the association to the class name. So the report for class `ExampleA` looks like that:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report-3.0.xsd" version="3.0.0-M4" name="ExampleA" time="5.69" tests="4" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
  <properties>
  ...
  </properties>
  <testcase name="[1] Foo1A" classname="ExampleA" time="0.185"/>
  <testcase name="[2] Bar1A" classname="ExampleA" time="0.003"/>
  <testcase name="[1] Foo2A" classname="ExampleA" time="0.003"/>
  <testcase name="[2] Bar2A" classname="ExampleA" time="0.003"/>
</testsuite>
```

This is my configuration of the `maven-sure-fire-plugin`:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>
                --illegal-access=permit
            </argLine>
            <statelessTestsetReporter
                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5Xml30StatelessReporter">
                <disable>false</disable>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <usePhrasedFileName>true</usePhrasedFileName>
                <usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>true</usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>
                <usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>
                <usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>
            </statelessTestsetReporter>
            <consoleOutputReporter
                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5ConsoleOutputReporter">
                <disable>false</disable>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
            </consoleOutputReporter>
            <statelessTestsetInfoReporter
                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5StatelessTestsetInfoReporter">
                <disable>false</disable>
                <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
                <usePhrasedClassNameInRunning>true</usePhrasedClassNameInRunning>
                <usePhrasedClassNameInTestCaseSummary>true</usePhrasedClassNameInTestCaseSummary>
            </statelessTestsetInfoReporter>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Is there a way to generate junit-style XML-Reports preserving the structure with maven? I aim for displaying the test results in [gitlab-ci](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/junit_test_reports.html#viewing-junit-test-reports-on-gitlab).

Comment: Which version of maven-surefire-plugin do you use?

Comment: The latest: 3.0.0-M4. I added it to the original post.

Comment: I believe that displaying these structurally is out of scope for generating the result XML. Jenkins parses the junit xml to create a structured/sorted html. I'm not sure about gitlab-ci, but I would assume they have a similart plugin. If not, you could check into clover and also get code coverage reports

Comment: Yes gitlab-ci is also able to parse the junit xml report. I am not sure what the limitations are because I am stuck with reproducing the structured view with maven surefire. But if you can reccomand any other plugin to generate those test-reports I am thankfull. I just need to execute the tests in my application based on their test-classes and need an deeper xml-tree of test-results representing the junit5 test hierarchy I created.

Comment: After further research it seems that there is a limitation in the XML-Report that is produced by JUnit5. There is an open issue since 2016 to improve the XSD behind. But I am not 100% certain that this is the right conclusion in this matter. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/373